# Не правильно работает передача данных TCP C++ C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, tcp

Проблема:
[image: На этом изображении сообщение "Hello"]

Вместо "Hello" получается "??o" последняя буква "o" и так всегда что делать?
Использовал разные коды и нечего(
Использую Soket-ы для передачи данных

Client C++:

```
void StartConnect(string in, string out)
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    cout << "startup: " << result << endl;

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8005);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    result = connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    cout << "Connect: " << result << endl;

    int count = 0;
    char sendBuf[512] = "Hello";
    int sendResult;
    sendResult = send(s, sendBuf, sizeof(sendBuf), 0);

}
```

Server c#:

```
        static int port = 8005; // порт для приема входящих запросов
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // получаем адреса для запуска сокета
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);

            // создаем сокет
            Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                // связываем сокет с локальной точкой, по которой будем принимать данные
                listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);

                // начинаем прослушивание
                listenSocket.Listen(10);

                Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений...");

                while (true)
                {
                    Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
                    // получаем сообщение
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байтов
                    byte[] data = new byte[512]; // буфер для получаемых данных

                    do
                    {
                        bytes = handler.Receive(data);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (handler.Available > 0);

                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + builder.ToString());

                    // отправляем ответ
                    string message = "ваше сообщение доставлено";
                    data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                    handler.Send(data);
                    // закрываем сокет
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Пробовал перекодировать в другой формат utf16 не получилось...
Но на клиенте и сервере на C# таких проблем не было, подскажите что делать?

Comment: Брейкпоинт поставьте перед выводом сообщения и побайтово сравните что хранится в буфере на сервере и клиенте. Если данные одинаковы, то смотрите в сторону кодировки.

Comment: Получилось, но много мусора:
"13:07: ??o?????  ??????Hello ??  ?????E????????????????   ?? ???????       ? ????????o?????  ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"
как исправить?

Comment: Ну, раз вы говорите что `на C# таких проблем не было`, то скорее всего вам придется делать свой конвертер для (де)сериализации в(из) буфер, т.к. плюсы и шарп пишут в разных форматах.

Comment: Складывается всё так, что нет готового решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Вам нужно на плюсах написать аналог `GetBytes`. Скорее всего вот это поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948808/c-equivalent-to-c-sharp-encoding-ascii-getbytes

Comment: Спасибо, попробую этот вариант

Comment: Не получилось, теперь вся мусором покрыта:"
16:08: ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"
Буду искать другой вариант

Comment: В C++ вы используете однобайтовую кодировку, в C# используется юникод.

Comment: Как перевести в юникод, однобайтовую кодировку?
Можно по подробнее.

Comment: Либо в C++ используйте `wchar`/`wstring`, либо в C# `Encoding.ASCII`

Comment: В коде сервера сделана классическая ошибка: читается кусок данных и преобразуется в кусок строки. Это работает только на однобайтовых кодировках. Для многобайтовых нужно читать данные полностью и лишь потом декодировать в текст.

Comment: Перевод в однобайтовую кодировку помог, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Здрасьте, приехали `Encoding.Unicode` - это UTF-16, а вы что ожидаете? Попробуйте UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перевод C# в `Encoding.ASCII` помог проблеме.

Comment: Вы не сможете передавать русский текст в ASCII. Попробуйте UTF8 и допишите перекодировку в плюсах. Не помню, как в плюсах включить UTF-8 в консоли, но помню, что можно.

Comment: А не кто и не говорит о русском тексте) передавать только английский текст и цифры.

Comment: `string message = "ваше сообщение доставлено"; data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message); handler.Send(data);` только я один это вижу?

Comment: Это с чего начал делать для проверки).